# Showing images of a post by hitting api endpoint using id from post [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, error-handling

I'm trying to retrieve images from a wp-json endpoint. First I need to retrieve the posts and using the image id in the post json, I retrieve the corresponding image. The code i wrote is done using resource, promises and services in the directive.

```
angular.module("madkoffeeFrontendApp")
  .directive("allarticles", ["articleService", "$q", "mediaService","userService", function(articleService, $q, mediaService,userService) {
    return {
      templateUrl: '../../views/articles.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope) {
        articleService.getArticles().$promise.then(function (argument) {
         scope.articles = argument;
         console.log(scope.articles);
       });

        scope.getImage = function (id) {
           mediaService.getMedia(id).$promise.then(function (argument) {
            console.log(argument.source_url);
             return argument.source_url;
          });
        }
```

My service for getArticles and getMedia is:

```
this.getArticles = function() {
   return articleResource.get();
}
this.getMedia = function(id){
return imgResource.get({fimgId:id});
}
```

articles.html template

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <article ng-repeat="post in articles" class="post">

          <a href="#" class="post-thumbnail-wrapper">
            <img src="{{getImage(post.featured_media)}}"></img>
          </a>
    </article>
    </div>
```

This code gives me errors like this:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

What can I do to improve this code? I simply need to fetch images using the id sent from the loop in the articles.html template. Should I use another way to write this code? If so what is it? Any solution?

Comment: You are reaching your watchers limit and AngularJS is aborting. Because you are  You can simply switch your structure. Will articles always reference their featured images?

Comment: All articles have a featured image associated. If there's an alternative structure to this, can you show a demo in plunker or jsfiddle? Even a pseudocode will be fine

Comment: can you setup the plunker with your example and error? i'll suggest a reorganization for you